# Fill a Rectangular with an inflating Circle without crossing its borders (Ripple)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, custom-controls, system.drawing

I have a control surface (my custom control) and a drawed rectangular smaller than the whole surface. Now I need to draw a circle (FillEllipse) within this rectangular and the circle must not overdraw the rectangular borders.

I made a ButtonStrip like this one know from Angular:
https://material.angular.io/components/button-toggle/overview
And want to create such ripples:
https://material.angular.io/components/ripple/examples

It is almost perfect. I would like to make such an animation. The filling progress is not a problem, but the fact, that I dont use kinda "child control buttons" in my ButtonStrip and therefore no "real" borders, I struggle with the not"over"drawing the borders of my clicked button.

And no, I will not use child buttons as controls to put into my strip. I dont want this control in control control. I am drawing the buttons and use the rectangulars as "address" for my events like Hover/Click/Clicked etc.

Here is an example of my ButtonStrip (Month is hovered). Day is clicked.

[image]

Every Button (in a List or Dictionary) has its own rectangular which is pre calculated:

```
Dim InnerWidth As Integer = If(_IOSwitchVisible = True,
    (Me.Width - _IOSwitchWidth) \ Buttons.Count,
    Me.Width \ Buttons.Count)

If InnerWidth = 0 Then Return

For Each b In Buttons.Values
    b.Rect = New Rectangle(CurrLeft, 0, InnerWidth, Me.Height)
    VerticalLinePos.Add(CurrLeft)
    CurrLeft += InnerWidth
Next
```

This is only a part of the code.
And here is a snippet how I draw a clicked button (either hovered or not)

```
'Clicked
For Each btn In Buttons.Values.ToList.Where(Function(x) x.Clicked = True)
    If _HoveredElement IsNot Nothing AndAlso _HoveredElement.Rect = btn.Rect Then
        'If the button is already clicked
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(ClickedHoveredColor), btn.Rect)
    Else
        'Otherwise draw clicked color
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(ClickedColor), btn.Rect)
    End If
Next
```

Does someone got an idea how to fill one of these buttons with a circle which must not overdraw to its neighbour buttons?

Edit: As soon as I (or you) found out how, I will include a loop to inflate the circle to animate a filling progress.

Comment: You can use a Timer to generate a growing ellipse, starting from a Rectangle inflated by negative values (so it's centered on the bounding rectangle - the colored area of your Button) and increase the inflate value while the rectangle's sides are contained within a measure that describes an ellipse that circumscribes the bounding rectangle (i.e., `ellipseMaxSize = new SizeF([Bounds].Width * (float)Math.Sqrt(2), [Bounds].Height * (float)Math.Sqrt(2))`) -- Set the clipping region temporarily to the bounding rectangle, so what is drawn outside, in the end, is not visible on screen.

Comment: If this is meant to be a WinForms Custom Control, tag your question accordingly.

Comment: Clipping! Thank you! I can set a clip Region, draw my increasing circle and then reset the clipping region! Thats the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jimi I got it working with his Clip hint:
[image]

(The yellow circle is from ScreenToGif)

```
Private Sub AnimateRipple(G As Graphics, C As Color, R As Rectangle)
    Dim ClipRegion As New Region(R)
    G.SetClip(ClipRegion, Drawing2D.CombineMode.Replace)

    Dim EllipseRect As Rectangle = R
    EllipseRect.Width = 1
    EllipseRect.Height = 1
    EllipseRect.Y = R.Height \ 2
    EllipseRect.X += R.Width \ 2

    EllipseRect.Inflate(InflateValue, InflateValue)
    Dim RippleBrush As SolidBrush = New SolidBrush(C)
    G.FillEllipse(RippleBrush, EllipseRect)
    G.ResetClip()
    RippleBrush.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).